# Присвоение ссылок объектов

Tags: объекты, ссылки, java

Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на условие в цикле `while`. Почему компилятор выдает ошибку `NullPointerException()` ? Объект `iterator` имеет тот же адрес, что и `next`. Потом `next` получает адрес объекта `newNode`. Вопрос: меняется-ли адрес объекта `iterator` и почему?

```
public void append(Node newNode) {
            Node iterator = next;
            if (next == null) {
                next = newNode;
            }
            while (iterator.next != null) {
                iterator = iterator.next;
            }
            iterator.next = newNode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: > Вопрос: меняется-ли адрес объекта iterator и почему?

Нет не получает. Потому, что на это нет причин.

Присвоение `next = newNode` не распространяет новое значение на `iterator`, т.к. `iterator` не ссылается на переменную `next`. `iterator` ссылается на объект и ничего не знает об изменении `next`.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему компилятор выдает ошибку NullPointerException() ?

Очевидно, потому что iterator == null

> Потом next получает адрес объекта newNode. Вопрос: меняется-ли адрес объекта iterator и почему?

Нет, просто ссылка next заменяется.

Может вы хотели так написать:

```
if (next == null) {
    next = newNode;
}
Node iterator = next;
```

Answer (score 0):

next - может быть null, для этого используется проверка

```
  if (next == null) {
```

В таком случае Node iterator = null, и строка:

```
  while (iterator.next != null) {
```

Выдаст ошибку NPE.
в случае

```
  next = newNode;
```

next - начинает ссылаеться на новый адрес памяти

Comment: newNode - это имя аргумента, никак не new Node();